# Running Script In AWS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rds

I don't know this is a relevant question or not? I have one csv file and 1 shape file in my own drive and I used to run one script in cmd and combined these two files and stored in a pgsql using pgfuttur. I want to do the same thing in aws. If I kept these two files on a bucket is it possible to do the same with the below command I used in cmd?

```
shp2pgsql -I "<Shape file directory>" <Tablename> | psql -U <username> -d <DatabaseName>  Example : shp2pgsql -I "C:\Test\filep" public.geo | psql -U postgres -d gisDB
```

if yes please help me to get this. If no please let me know the reason.. [Please note that I am new to AWS]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1. You plan to do it only once or few times: Download the files locally using AWS CLI: [aws s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) or [aws s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) and then pass those files as input
2. You will be accessing multiple files: Use another AWS service to expose your S3 objects as files. Check [AWS Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/) and choose [AWS Storage Gateway for Files](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/file/). Once configured, you can refer to the S3 objects as files.